# Does not implement interface member 'System.Icomparable.CompareTo(object)'?

Tags: c#

I got this message because I wrote a class implemented the Icomparable:

```
class Person: IComparable<Person>
    {
        public int age{get;set;}
        public String name { get; set; }

        int IComparable.CompareTo( Person p )
        {
            if (this.age > p.age)
                return 1;
            else if (this.age == p.age)
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;

        }

    }
```

Cannot figure out what was wrong in it, any one has any good ideas?

P.S., I changed the param into object but still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method declaration left off the generic argument.  It needs to be

```
int IComparable<Person>.CompareTo(Person p)
```

Without the generic argument the compiler believes you are trying to implement the non-generic interface `IComparable`.

Comment: @user1804033 what error exactly?  The code sample you provided compiles just fine if you make the change I suggested (verified it myself)

Comment: worked! the error was gone after I started the program, thank you very much!
btw, when implementing the interface, I should always put InterfaceName.Method()?

Comment: @user1804033 it depends.  That specific form is called explicit interface implementation.  In **general** the common form is to just make the method public instead of explicit.  Example `public int CompareTo(Person p)`.  But there is nothing wrong with explicit implementation

Comment: @user1804033 it's time to accept the answer, don't forget it.

Comment: @JaredPar you made a perfect point from the beginning to the end, thank you for helping me so much and making this place a better one!!! Have a good one!

Answer (score 3):

```
class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        if (age > other.age)

        { return 1; }
        if (age == other.age)
        { return 0; }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your implementation should look like.

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Person p = obj as Person;
        if (this.age > p.age)
            return 1;
        else if (this.age == p.age)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    }
```